# How can I force a "destination net unreachable" ping result in Windows

Tags: networking, ping

I am working on a program that connects to various Windows computers and runs automated scripts.

One of the scripts checks for general Internet connectivity through few means, including pinging public websites and/or IPs.

When the ping in unusccessful the error reasons are:

1. request timed out
2. destination host unreachable
3. destination net unreachable

I need to test the response handler for this script, and to do so, I need to force a ping to respond with each of the above reasons. Request timed out is easy, I just ping any fake ip address or hostname. I can reliably get destination host unreachable responses by pining a fake local ip addresses on the same subnet as the machine.

However, I cannot find a way to produce 'destination net unreachable' responses. I've tried editing the machines host file with something like `1.2.3.4 example.com`, but this just results in a "request timed out" response. I've also tried adding fake arp entries along the lines of `arp -s 1.2.3.4 aa-bb-cc-aa-bb-cc` with the same result.

How can I configure a Windows 10 machine produce `destination net unrechable` ping respones in a consistent manner?

Comment: Your router needs to _not_ have a route to the destination network in its routing table. You probably have a default route (`0.0.0.0/0`) that matches every destination address. You need to remove that default route and try to ping something on the Internet.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there any way to bypass this via desktop configuration? Unfortunately I am not able to access the router's settings.

Comment: That is something generated when a network destination is not in a routing table. You may be able to remove the default route from your host and try to ping something on a network not in the host routing table, but you do risk screwing up the host.

Comment: Use a hacked ping—e.g., pretend net 10 is unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the destination net unreachable error when your computer fails to find the route to the network address of the remote IP address you ping.

The best way to create this error scenario is to remove the default route from the routing table in the router configuration as suggested by  Ron Maupin.

Another method is to edit the Windows 10 routing table on your computer and connect to a direct modem in a bridge mode. You can use third-party tools to do this work easily. Then try to ping a destination address where no route available. It will definitely result in a destination net unreachable error.
https://www.corenetworkz.com/2009/05/destination-net-unreachable-icmp-error.html